# Markdown blockquote failure

Tags: jquery, html, css, markdown, wmd-markdown

I'm using [this jQuery markdown](https://github.com/arhpreston/jquery-markdown/blob/master/markdown/Markdown.Converter.js) for my pages. The jQuery code is as follows:

```javascript
var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#content').html( converter.makeHtml($('#content').html()) );
    /* and some more */
});
```

This has been working perfectly. None of my pages had a `blockquote` until now. Today, I tried using a `blockquote` content and the page isn't parsing the HTML correctly.

The text is stored inside a MySQL table. Consider the following:

```
Just some

> random blockquote content. let's see if it works or not
```

This text is shown correctly on the [markdown editor box](https://github.com/arhpreston/jquery-markdown/blob/master/markdown/Markdown.Editor.js):

> [image: WMD]

But when opening it as a web-page (I use Opera; but the problem is still there in all other browsers, namely Firefox, Chrome and IE)

1. The normal page shows

   > [image: page]
2. Opera Dragonfly

   > [image: dragonfly]
3. Raw text as page source

   > [image: source]

**P.S.**: All images are thumbnails. Click for larger size.

### Here is a fiddle link which shows the above problem: http://jsfiddle.net/atdEP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jay I've found a solution to the problem.

Instead of using `.html()` in the converter, it performs perfectly with `.text()`.

```
var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#content').html( converter.makeHtml($('#content').text()) );
    /* and some more --------------------- RIGHT HERE  >>>^ */
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atdEP/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familar with markdown, but i think you are picking up the > as an html entity I.E `&gt;` and not a single character.

If I change your fiddle by hardcoding the string to the below, the > disappears from the results screen and the correct html appears. (tested in firebug)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#content').html(converter.makeHtml('> random blockquote'));
        /* and some more */
    });
</script>
```